# Set button active when form is filled (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following controller and directive:

```
app.controller('controlFormulario', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var cf = this;
  cf.formulario = [];
  cf.formulario.fecha = new Date();

  if(cf.formulario.texto != null && cf.formulario.titulo != null){
    this.formulario.isDisabled = false;
  }
}]);

app.directive('formulario', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E', // C: class, E: element, M: comments, A: attributes
    templateUrl: 'modules/formulario.html',

  };
}]);
```

And this is the DOM element of the button, the one I want to enable when there is some text in the title and text fields:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-init="formCtrl.formulario.isDisabled = true">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" style="height:35px;width:100px;float:right;" id="submit" disabled={{formCtrl.formulario.isDisabled}}>
  Enviar
  </button>
</div>
```

Currently, the controller function that enables the button, isn't working at all. I've got it instantiated in the main div of the formulary, and it's working properly with the data binding, but it's somehow not enabling the button.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ng-disabled`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) instead of the `disabled` attribute.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="height:35px;width:100px;float:right;" id="submit" ng-disabled="formCtrl.formulario.isDisabled">
```

From the linked documentation:

> A special directive is necessary because we cannot use interpolation
>   inside the `disabled` attribute.

Also, use `$scope` to expose your data to the view, not `this`. [`this` refers to the controller, not to the `$scope` that the view can see.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14168699/3900404)

Comment: it's not working, somehow the controller functionality it's not the one I expected. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-disabled` instead of `disabled`